# Multi-Label-Classification Approach to complex tabular data structure in R

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, multiclass-classification, data-preprocessing

I have a set of two dataframes that both contain duplicates but need to be merged into one big dataframe in order to use it as input for an ML algorithm.
Connecting the two dataframes is a big problem in the first place. Furthermore, it is difficult to predict multiple classes from the resulting dataset.
Since the original dataset has its origin in the medical field and is confidential, I added a fictional (though realistic) example code for a reproduction of the problem below.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data1 <- data.table("color" = c("green", "green", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "pink"),
"type" = c("SUV", "SUV", "SEDAN", "SEDAN", "SEDAN", "TRUCK", "TRUCK", "CABRIO", "CABRIO"),
"NUM_SEATS" = c(4,4,5,4,4,3,3,2,2),
"MODELL_ID" = c("xyz", "xyz", "abc", "abc", "abc", "rtz", "rtz", "ghj", "ghj"))

data2 <- data.table("BRAND" = c("VW", "VW", "VW", "AUDI", "AUDI", "BMW", "BMW", "GM", "GM"),
"year_quarter" = c("20173", "20173", "20174", "20174", "20171", "20181", "20162", "20172", "20192"),
"MODELL_ID" = c("xyz", "xyz", "abc", "abc", "abc", "rtz", "rtz", "ghj", "ghj"))
data1 <- data1 %>% group_by(MODELL_ID) %>% mutate(time = row_number()) %>% ungroup()
data2 <- data2 %>% group_by(MODELL_ID) %>% mutate(time = row_number()) %>% ungroup()

data1_temp <- data1 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = c(-MODELL_ID), names_sort = TRUE, names_sep = "-")
data2_temp <- data2 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = c(-MODELL_ID), names_sort = TRUE, names_sep = "-")
data_join <- inner_join(data1_temp, data2_temp, by = c("MODELL_ID")) %>% select(-starts_with(c("n.", "time"))) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "MODELL_ID", values_from = "MODELL_ID", names_prefix = "MODELL_ID-") %>% as.matrix()
data_join[is.na(data_join)] <- "0"

x_data <- data_join %>% as.data.table() %>% select(-starts_with("MODELL_ID-"))
y_data <- data_join %>% as.data.table() %>% select(starts_with("MODELL_ID-"))

x_data # input (unvectorized)
y_data # output (unvectorized)

x_data %>% data.matrix()-1 # input (vectorized)
y_data %>% data.matrix()-1 # output (vectorized)
```

**X is my input (`x_data`), `Modell_ID` (`y_data`) my output**. I want my ML solution to predict all possible `Modell_ID`s when given a row of X.

It would be great to get some advise on how to `actually implement` a solution for this. Every approach so far (Feed-Forward Net, etc.) has not delivered noticeable results...

I am really looking for a game-changing command, approach, example code rather than just superficial tips.

Comment: How many observations e.g. samples do you have? Do they come from different batches (e.g. studies aggreaged over multiple countries or years)? Do you want to optmize explanatory power or out of training test predictive power? What is your power metric (e.g. AUC, accuracy,...)? Do you care about generalization?

Comment: @danloo Thanks for your interest

1. We have around 50.000.000 rows in our input dataframe (and over 100 columns)  
2. We got three different sql tables from three different data sources (medical field) and created one big dataframe out of them after transferring them from an Oracle database into R, then we normalized and vectorized the data  
3. We mostly care about the overall accuracy, since the output contains real-world medical diagnosis
4. We have around 700 output labels
5. For each group, we currently "open" a new column, since the three datasets can only be combined that way

Comment: One usually should not for just accuracy. Sensitivity and specificity (or combined in AUC) are very important as well, especially in the field of medical diagnosis. Do you really want to optimize just for accuracy? Do you predict rare (y=1 in less than one out of 100 samples) or common events?

Comment: @danloo We don't '"just" care about accuracy but predominantly since AUC is important as well but harder to interpret in our development stage. We currently define a diagnosis as worth mentioning if the model predicts this type of diagnosis with a prob > 0.5